# Spring Integration handle http outbound gateway failures

Tags: spring, spring-integration

There are multiple servers that are listening to activemq. The chain is configured to make the http [outbound gateway] call. Suppose one of the server picks up the message and in-between if the http call fails for some reason. The message should be put back to the queue, so that another server can pick up the message and process. Can this be achieved using Spring Integration. I read lot on Transaction, however unable to find workable way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply set `acknowledge="transacted"` on the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter/>` and, as long as you use only direct channels (no `<queue/>` on the channel or `task-executor` on the channel's dispatcher) then any failure will cause the message to roll back.

Comment: The task-executor is configured on the channel `<int:channel id="UChannel"> <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor"/> </int:channel> <int-jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="UChannel" request-destination-name="U" extract-request-payload="true" /> <int:chain input-channel="UChannel"> <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://localhost/u.php?fileid={fileid}" http-method="GET"> <int-http:uri-variable name="fileid" expression="headers.fileid"/> </int-http:outbound-gateway> <int:object-to-string-transformer /> </int:chain>`

Comment: Transactions in Spring only work on a single thread; as soon as you hand off to another thread, the current thread will return to the container and commit immediately. You cannot use `ExecutorChannel`s or `QueueChannel`s in this scenario. You need to use only `DirectChannel`s only. If you need concurrency, that should be handled using the concurrency settings on the `message-driven-adapter`; that way each message is fully processed on its own thread.